# Google Analytics: Profile Workaround

Tags: google-analytics

I currently have more than 50 microsites on my main websites. That is I have one main top level domain and I have more than 50 microsites (and growing) in subfolders on that domain.

Previously I used separate GA web properties for the separate microsites (different GA tracking ID's), which worked fine and I was able to track each sites' activity well. However, I talked to a GA staffer over email and he told me I should switch to using a singular GA web property and use multiple profiles to segment the data by subfolder/microsite. That seemed logical for a lot of reasons, tracking users over the entirety of the website in one GA session being the main one.

Anyway, I have one subfolder which houses an array of microsites, numbering almost 40 right now. I don't necessarily need to have a profile for each one of these sites but there are a couple of important ones that I need to report on individually and on a regular basis I'd like to see how traffic to the other individual sites are doing.

So my question: Is there a way in a single profile to segment data to 40+ (and growing) microsites and see month to month stats on each site? Is there a way I can load a profile dashboard with the stats (Visits/pageviews) from each microsite? Is segmenting the data even what I should be looking at? How would you, a more advanced GA user, tackle this problem?

Many thanks for your input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jimdo (http://www.jimdo.com) offers a Google Analytics based statistics tool for their DIY website creator. They put hundreds of the (usually low traffic) sites in one profile, set a custom var with a unique ID per site and query the results via the Google API, segmented by site id (at least that is what one of their founders told during a web analytics conference a few months ago). Given that the solution works for a couple of million of client sites (their claim is to host 7 million websites for their clients) segmentation based on a unique site id seems a pretty solid idea.

Updated: As custom vars are deprecated with Universal Analytics you'd now use a custom dimension instead if a custom var. Apart from that the approach should still work.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response! Can you point me in the direction on any documentation to this technique? It sounds promising.

Comment: I only know what they chose to divulge in their conference speech - they generated a hash value based on the domain name for segmentation via custom vars and used the API to pull the data to a custom interface so they didn't have to create millions of logins (they seem to have an occasional problem with data sampling where sampled reports draw data from multiple segments). That's all I know, but it should be enough to get you going.

Comment: Btw. if you choose this technique and need Logins for individual users I'd recommend to use Google App Script + Google spreadsheets - there you can create a nice custom report with a few dozen lines of Javascript. This should be much easier to maintain than a bespoke server application for API access.

Comment: Seems like a valid way to go about doing it, though probably overkill in my case. I may have to just go with a mix of Profiles and Advanced Segments to get the data i want, although I haven't found a way to completely segment data into a subfolder without using a profile. Anyway, thanks for your input, I'll mark the topic answered. Though if anyone has any other techniques feel free to contribute.