# How to setup Google Analytics account structure for large collection of sites

Tags: google-analytics

We manage a large collection of websites that each fit into a couple of dozen categories.  Some of the categories have hundreds of sites in them.  The largest of which is over 800 sites.  I would like to set up my Google Analytics account structure to facilitate easily reporting on individual sites, categories, and overall enterprise wide traffic.

For example, let's say our categories are food, sports, and politics each with 300 sites.  I will need to be able to report on the number of site visits for each individual website, aggregate numbers for all food sites, all sports sites, and all political sites, and aggregate numbers for all 900 sites combined.

To get the overall numbers (all sites/categories combined) it seems easy enough to create a rollup account and use that tracking code along with another tracking code on each page.  Where I'm struggling is how to get the category-wide numbers and the site-level numbers.  I've thought about two approaches:

1. Create a custom dimension for category and then build custom reports keyed off the custom dimension.  This would allow me to group the accounts however I see fit as long as the custom dimension is reported to the rollup account.
2. Create multiple properties for each category and associate each with a "lead" site for that category.  This would require site-level reports being based on hostname or something similar.

It seems the limiting factor is each account cannot have more than 50 views.  Following Google's advice to always keep an unfiltered view of your data plus views for whatever filters are desired means I will need dozens of accounts unless there is some creative approach I haven't thought about.

Any suggestions on how to best setup the accounts, properties and views to facilitate the site-level, category-level and enterprise-wide reports?

Comment: Your first approach is actually used by a large company with similar problems (they did a conference speech about some two years ago), see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468190/google-analytics-profile-workaround/14475326#14475326

Comment: Thanks for the response! Sounds like I am on the right track.