# Use Google Analytics for individual users

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I have a website where people post items and I want to show some basic analytics in their own user panels, such as how many people viewed the posted item.

I am wondering if I can use a single mothership Google Analytics account across the whole site. Then, in my code for the user area, I have it query Google Analytics for that specific users posts and return the number of visits that specific person has had.

So my google analytics account may say "200 views across the whole site" but within the specific users panel I will be able to say "Your posts received 50 views".

This is the closest bit of documentation I could find on the subject:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/

Comment: While not quite a duplicate the answer from here applies: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468190/google-analytics-profile-workaround/14475326#14475326

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you would need is multiple Google Analytics IDs / requests per page. This can be done with the newest version of Analytics, though not with the Classic Analytics.

You can certainly have multiple Google accounts access the single Google Analytics for a single domain. You can certainly split reporting capabilities and access to various Analytics features across multiple accounts.

From the docs:

> You can install multiple instances of the Google Analytics tracking
>   code on your web pages to send data to multiple properties in your
>   account.

Read: [more here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032400?hl=en).

Comment: I don't really want to involve more than one google account, but I was hoping when I query google analytics to show the vistor numbers on my website within the control panel I can do something like this (sudo code):
***for url */james/ show $visitornumber***