# Google Analytics for website users

Tags: google-analytics, web-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I operate a high-traffic website, where users have a public page (e.g. website.com/users/$USERNAME ) and would like to create analytics for them. Instead of re-inventing the wheel, the best would be if I could leverage google analytics directly.

It's not a problem is users opt-in to this scheme, and give me their google account name. One idea was to create custom analytics views for users, but it seems there's a limit of 25 views per properties.

Another thing I was looking at, is using Google Analytics segments, but it seems that segments are scoped to a subset of users or sessions, while I want it on certain page-hits only.

I could also dynamically use their google analytics code, if it was scoped to a single page.

Is this use-case something that Google analytics supports, or should I develop a home rolled solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Analytics: Profile Workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468190/google-analytics-profile-workaround)

Comment: Is your intent to have them log on to Google Analytics to see their statistics?  If so, then I think you would need to insert their tracking code into their public page.  Or were you trying to build a small dashboard so users could see statistics about their page WITHIN your website/app?  In this latter case you could accomplish this using the core reporting api and a filter.  Example: ga:pagesource%3D%3D/users/MYPAGE     I founded a web app called EmbeddedAnalytics. We do all sorts of GA based dashboarding for listing/CMS sites.  Site is http://www.embeddedanalytics.com