# Google analytis share data with different users

Tags: google-analytics

I have a projet with some number of customers (more than 25). Each customer has theirs own subdomain (customer1.mydomain.com, customer2.mydomain.com, ...). I want to track pageviews from all domains and have one report for all domains for me as administrator. Each customer should be allowed so see reports, but only for his domain.

Example:
account: UA-XXXXXX-Y
customer1.mydomain.com and customer2.mydomain.com send data to this acccount
as administrator I can see all this data, add segments, divided by hosts. Also I can create views for these segments and allow users (customer1, customer2) to see only data from these segments. But google allows to add only 25 views and I have more that 25 customers.

Also I tryed to create several account and send pageview for my administrator account and then to current customer account, but ga('craete', 'another-ua') command doesn't recreate instane with new account, just using first created one.

Anyone can suggest any solution wih allows:

1. As administrator, I want see all data sepaated by hosts
2. As customer, I want to see only my own data and should not be able to see any other data

Comment: As I see it you have two options; One would be to include all in a single tracking account and then segment the data using filters (or properties I think they're called at the moment) for each customers. The second would be to include two trackers on solutions. One for the customer and one 'combined' for you.

Comment: Yes, but I can't use segments because I need to allow customers to see only theirs own data. Google allows create only 25 views, which can be shared with customers. I'll have muh more users.

How to create two different trackers on the page? or maybee there is a solution with google analytics api, which can be called from the backend side?

Comment: It's going to be more work, but multiple trackers: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/creating-trackers#working_with_multiple_trackers But it'll allow you to completely separate data

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen thanks a lot, this solution should work perfectly, I'll add answer later when it will be implemented and tested

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Analytics: Profile Workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468190/google-analytics-profile-workaround)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @AllanS.Hansen wrote, this comment works:

It's going to be more work, but multiple trackers: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/creating-trackers#working_with_multiple_trackers. But it'll allow you to completely separate data