# Google analytics for saas platform

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, saas

I've built a software that basically works as an CMS/Commerce for my clients. They point their domain address to my server and I take care of technical details and infra.

That said, I need a way of tracking Google Analytics for all my clients in a way that I can see client-individual info or consolidate (all domains).
Considering the software is the same for all of my clients, they have the same url structure and functionalities.

I need to be able to get my overall conversion rate and compare it to one of my clients.

My approach was to change the tracker name like this

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1', 'client1');
ga('client1.send', 'pageview');
```

And than filter in the GA panel by client by tracker name or apply no filter and see consolidate data.

Is it possible? What am I missing?

I probably cannot afford to use multiple properties (distinct by client) because GA limits 50 properties by account. My goal is to reach many times this limitation.

Keep in mind that I'm dealing with multiple domains.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think the tracker name is actually visible in the reports. You need something else to filter by like a custom dimension (and there is an answer for that).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Analytics: Profile Workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468190/google-analytics-profile-workaround)

Comment: @EikePierstorff I don't agree. The user in that post is dealing with a single domain. I'm not sure I can use the same approach

Comment: The point is that you need to have a field to segment by, and the tracker name won't help you. If they are on different domains you can use the approach from the linked post and build segments by hostname (but it would work with custom dimensions, too, different domains nonwithstanding. GA is not really concerned on which domain the tracking code runs).

Comment: @EikePierstorff I think I've got your point. Could you please point me to some code that exemplify what you meant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This topic got solved by using Google Analytics custom dimensions.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828