# How to track hundreds of websites all together with google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain, analytics, web-analytics

I have a Content Management System which let people create websites. the CMS has multiple theme and color schemes which they can choose. Every website created using this CMS has a unique domain (www.abc.com, ww.xyz.com etc).

Product In detail:

I have a website mywebsite.com people can signup there, buy their own domain and create their own website at mywebsite.com. so now they have their own xyz.com website where user can add content from mywebsite.com

All these websites are independent, they just share the same code as they all are using my CMS but they have their own content (pictures, videos, text)
I would like to track the statistics of all these websites all together. It is not a problem if a user goes to abc.com and then goes to xyz.com is counted as different session because they are totally different websites and I want google to count them separately.

I want to do this to check how much views my product is getting as whole. which is the best way to achieve this.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Analytics: Profile Workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468190/google-analytics-profile-workaround)

Comment: @EikePierstorff oh no its not.

Comment: Oh yes it is (your business model is exactly the same, and this solution will give you both the totals and the breakdowns by client sites).  But nevermind, basically all you have to do is to use the same GA account for all your pages and you'll get the totals. Google Analytics is not bothered by the domain it is installed on, it will track all visits to the account specific in the tracking id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're after here is what is referred to as a "roll up" account, this is as standard a feature available in Google Analytics Premium (or 360 as it's now known).

However assuming you don't have the financial resources to drop £100k on a Google Analytics premium account you can achieve *similar* through double tagging on the same website.

This is fairly straight forward and you can see Google's documentation on this on the link below:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/creating-trackers#specifying_fields_at_creation_time

As an example:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Z', 'auto', 'rollupTracker');

ga('send', 'pageview');
ga('rollupTracker.send', 'pageview');
```

Where `UA-XXXXX-Z` is your property ID for the roll-up account and `UA-XXXXX-Y` is your users' default tracking code.

Note there are a few caveats to using roll-up views:

- Even with cross domain tracking you could end up with more than one session across domains for the same user (if they landed on site A then separately landed on Site B before clicking back to site A)
- You could hit the rate limits and sampling limits imposed by Google pretty quicky.
- You'll need to use either View filters and/or advanced segments to see the statistics of separate websites and this will only exasperate the issue of sampling limitations.

Detail of the premium Analytics implementation is available over at Luna Metrics:
http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2015/02/03/rollup-data-google-analytics/

Comment: Alternatively, if you don't want to do the double tagging method, then Simo Ahava's got a solution to fire tags multiples of times (or twice): http://www.simoahava.com/analytics/firing-a-single-tag-multiple-times-in-gtm/#gref

Comment: Bear in mind that requires the use of GTM rather than a pure analytics setup (and would still require separate tags)

Comment: @williamvicary thank you for the answer William, however  
I added some more details to the question to be more clear, could you please read it again?

Comment: @ANshulSharma Just read your updates and my answer remains, you can "double tag" the properties (or simply add your own tag manually with a different trackerName and ignore the user's tag, as long as it's uniquely named it shouldn't conflict) and this will create the rolled up view you're after.

Comment: @williamvicary is it possible that i use same analytic code in every website and then create filters in the views to check the views of the individual websites?

Answer (score 0):

This is a huge ask.

Google Analytics relies heavily on cookies, which are unique to the domain. This means that if Person A is on Site 1, and moves to site 2, your Google Analytics has no way of knowing that that was the same person; they will effectively become a new person every time the domain changes.

Now that's not a problem if you're going to have no links between the sites (although you may want to look into prepending hostnames http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2015/12/10/basic-google-analytics-filters/#Prepend Hostname to Request URI)

But if you're going to link the sites together then it gets a bit more complicated. You're going to have to set up cross-domain tracking (http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2015/06/16/cross-domain-tracking-with-google-tag-manager/) on each of these, which is best done using Google Tag Manager. Now depending on your implementation this could be a real headache for you, as this requires the GTM container for each site to have a list that names all of the other sites. This list would need to be updated on every container each time you add a site. However, you can make this significantly simpler if you just go for a straight-up Page View tag, and use the same container on each page.

Comment: I don't think cross domain tracking is relevant here - these seem to be separate client sites, not something interconnected. Just tracking them and piping segments by hostname (or some other identifier) to a dashboard software should be good enough.

Comment: thank you for the answer Brazier, however  
I added some more details to the question to be more clear, could you please read it again?

Comment: @EikePierstorff is correct then; you don't need cross-domain tracking, you just need to attach the same code to each site, and provide an identifier such as a prepended hostname, as in the link in my post.